# Настройка TexStudio под Windows 7

Tags: latex

У меня на компе с W7 был TexLive. Дополнительно поставил TexStudio. Он предупреждает мол "не могу найти ничего, поставьте TexLive или ещё что-то". Я хочу вручную прописать пути. Как и где это сделать? Выставить переменные окружения? В TexStudio в Options -> Configure TexStudio -> вкладка Commands вроде можно прописать какие-то пути, но там довольно много настроек: PdfLatex, Latex, DviLatex и т.д. И в texlive я нашёл папку bin, там тоже довольно много экзешников. Видимо нужно прописать пути именно к этим экзешникам, но к каким именно?

В идеале было бы неплохо увидеть скриншот с TexStudio, настроенным под TexLive. Чтобы было видно в какую графу путь к какому именно экзешнику прописывать.

Или, быть может, лучше переустановить texlive дабы TexStudio его нормально увидел?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается при установке TexLive можно вручную выставить опцию чтобы установщик прописал в Path необходимые пути. После переустановки TexLive TexStudio самостоятельно всё инициализировал -- соответствующие вызовы программ и параметры командной строки к ним.
При этом отмечу, что в переменную Path прописываются соответствующие скрипты тиа latex.exe, pdflatex.exe и т.п.